# v2.ODataModel.refresh(true) gets updated data but doesn't update the model

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am running into a weird issue with the [`sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel#refresh` API](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel#methods/refresh) that prevents my UI from updating properly.

I am using a Multi Select Table via which I allow two different types of Updates that I have implemented identically

```js
// Base Controller
getModel(name, global = false) {
   const scope = global ? this.getOwnerComponent() : this.getView();
   return scope.getModel(name);
},

updateEntry(model, path, data, options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const parameters = {
            ...options,
            success: (data, response) => {
                resolve({ data, response });
            },
            error: error => {
                reject(error);
            },
        };

        model.update(path, data, parameters);
    });
},
```

```js
// Table Controller, Update Handler for both scenarios, Model "main" is bound via List Binding to my Table
onUpdate: async function (oEvent) {
    const bContinue = await SubmitDialog.init.call(this);
    if (!bContinue) return;
    const srv = this.getModel("main", true);
    // ... Fetching Table Data / some additional logic
    const aUpdates = [];
    aAssets.forEach(asset => {
        // ... Updating fields setting uri etc.
        aUpdates.push(this.updateEntry(srv, `/EntitySet${uri}`, body, { groupId: "update", refreshAfterChange: false }));
    });
    await Promise.all(aUpdates);
    srv.refresh(true);
},
```

and finally in the same controller

```js
onAfterRendering: function () {
    this.byId("table").getBinding("items").attachDataReceived(() => {
        console.log("Model after update", this.getModel("main").getProperty("/"));
        this._initUIData(); // some UI changes
    });
},
```

The Update handler functions exactly as I am expecting it to. I first do a $batch request with all my updates followed by a $batch GET request to get the updated data to then modify my UI accordingly (i.e. displaying counters in an Icon Tab Bar etc.)

However, for one of the scenarios I can see that, although the payload I am receiving after the GET request reflects my changes, the model is simply not updated, so that my logic to update the UI fails. I am assuming that it is somehow related to my `dataReceived` event handler, but I am honestly not sure why. FWIW in one of the update handlers (the one that is working properly), I am closing a Dialog after the `srv.refresh(true)` but that's about the only thing that is different.

It may also be worth mentioning that **I use `Client` operation mode for my OData model.**

Any hints or ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: With `refreshAfterChange` set to `true`, you wouldn't need to call `refresh(true)` in the first place. Or what is the reason for `refreshAfterChange: false`? Are you seeing multiple GET URIs for each update in the $batch request?

Comment: It seemed I hadn't control over the sequence of the batch requests with `refreshAfterChange` set to `true`, i.e. the GET was firing before all Updates were completed.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. According to the documentation: _> "[...] The OData V2 model automatically puts all change sets at the beginning of a batch request. **All GET requests are put after them.** [...]"_ (Source: https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2#loio8a6ae1d390534d05a560bf350af59c29) The same behavior is also implemented in the OData V4 stack.

Comment: I just gave this another go and you are absolutely right - I believe when I had tried this initially I was causing this behaviour due to some other issues in my code. However, I am still running into the same issue, i.e. getting correct response but no update onto the actual model - I belive due to the reason I have outlined in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I may have found the solution. My second update scenario (the one that hasn't updated the model) is an update, that causes the list entries to no longer appear in my table. I believe in this case the following condition of the [`v2.ODataModel#refresh`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel#methods/refresh) is not met, even though I had set the 1st parameter `bForceUpdate` to `true`.

> This will reload all data stored in the model. This will check all bindings for **updated data** and **update the controls if data has been changed**.

I have now set the 2nd parameter `bRemoveData` to `true` as well and this seems to have fixed my issue.